# How to set increase or decrease function in cart

Tags: javascript, cart, product-quantity

when i select the item in cart, it is selected. But when i try to increase the quantity, the price does not change and i have to recheck to update the price. Please help as i cannot figure out how to increase the price when i increase or decrease the quantity of item. I also cannot put increase/decrease function in selectBtn as it would become a loop of number

```js
let quantities = document.querySelectorAll(".quantity-number");
let plusAll = document.querySelectorAll(".plus");
let minusAll = document.querySelectorAll(".minus");

quantities.forEach((quantity, index) => {
  let plus = plusAll[index];
  let minus = minusAll[index];
  plus.addEventListener("click", () => {
    quantity.innerHTML++;
    if (quantity.innerHTML > 1) {
      minus.disabled = false;
    }
  })
  minus.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (quantity.innerHTML <= 1) {
      minus.disabled = true;
    } else {
      minus.disabled = false;
      quantity.innerHTML--;
    }
  })
});

let items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
document.querySelector("title").innerHTML =
  items.length + " items found in Cart";

let prices = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
let selectBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".select");
let selectAll = document.querySelector(".selectAll");
let totalItem = document.querySelectorAll(".totalItem");
let totalPrice = document.querySelector(".totalPrice");
let finalPrice = document.querySelector(".finalPrice");

selectBtn.forEach((btn, index) => {
  let price = Number(prices[index].innerHTML);

  selectAll.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (selectAll.checked == true) {
      if (btn.checked == false) {
        btn.checked = true;
        let quantity = Number(quantities[index].innerHTML);
        if (quantity == 1) {
          price = price;
        } else {
          price = Number(prices[index].innerHTML);
          price = price * quantity;
        };
        totalItem.forEach((total) => {
          total.innerHTML++;
        })
        if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
          totalPrice.innerHTML = (price).toFixed(2);
          finalPrice.innerHTML = (4 + Number(totalPrice.innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
        } else {
          totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + price).toFixed(2);
          finalPrice.innerHTML = (4 + Number(totalPrice.innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
        }
      }
    } else {
      btn.checked = false;
      totalItem.forEach((total) => {
        total.innerHTML--;
      })
      totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) - price).toFixed(2);
      if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
        finalPrice.innerHTML = 0;
      } else {
        finalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + 4).toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  })

  btn.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (btn.checked) {
      let quantity = Number(quantities[index].innerHTML);
      if (quantity == 1) {
        price = price;
      } else {
        price = Number(prices[index].innerHTML);
        price = price * quantity;
      };

      totalItem.forEach((total) => {
        total.innerHTML++;
      })
      if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
        totalPrice.innerHTML = (price).toFixed(2);
        finalPrice.innerHTML = (4 + Number(totalPrice.innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
      } else {
        totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + price).toFixed(2);
        finalPrice.innerHTML = (4 + Number(totalPrice.innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
      }
    } else {
      totalItem.forEach((total) => {
        total.innerHTML--;
      })
      selectAll.checked = false;
      totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) - price).toFixed(2);
      if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
        finalPrice.innerHTML = 0;
      } else {
        finalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + 4).toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="scroll-smooth">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-[#f5f4f4] hide-scrollbar">

  <div class="">
    <h2 class="text-3xl text-center py-8">Your Cart</h2>
    <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3">
      <div class="grid space-y-4 col-span-2">
        <div class="flex justify-between bg-white mx-4 px-4 py-2 border-black border ">
          <div class="flex space-x-4 items-center">
            <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">
            <p>SELECT ALL</p>
          </div>
          <button>
                        <img class="w-8 h-8" src="../images/main/delete.png" alt="">
                    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="item flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-white mx-4 space-x-2 border-black border">
          <input class="select rounded-full" type="checkbox" name="" id="">
          <img class="w-20 h-20" src="../images/Cowin-Blue-Wholesale-Aviation-Active-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones-Wired-Gaming-Earphones-Headsets-Bluetooth-Headphones-Wireless/prod1.webp" alt="">
          <div class="grid grod-rows-2 w-full">
            <p class="text-justify text-sm line-clamp-2">Cowin Blue Wholesale: Aviation Active Noise Cancelling Headphones, Wired Gaming Earphones, Headsets, Bluetooth Headphones, Wireless</p>
            <div class="flex justify-between">
              <div class="grid grid-rows-2">
                <p class="text-base font-bold">$<span class="text-xl price">59.99</span></p>
                <p class="text-xs">$<del class="text-sm">79.99</del></p>
              </div>
              <div class="quantity flex items-center space-x-2 py-2 text-white">
                <button class="minus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&minus;</button>
                <p class="quantity-number text-black">1</p>
                <button class="plus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&plus;</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-white mx-4 space-x-2 border-black border">
          <input class="select rounded-full" type="checkbox" name="" id="">
          <img class="w-20 h-20" src="../images/Modern-soft-and-comfortable-office-E-sports-club-chair-designed-for-ergonomic-gaming-on-computers/prod1.webp" alt="">
          <div class="grid grod-rows-2 w-full">
            <p class="text-justify text-sm line-clamp-2">Modern, soft, and comfortable office E-sports club chair designed for ergonomic gaming on computers</p>
            <div class="flex justify-between">
              <div class="grid grid-rows-2">
                <p class="text-base font-bold">$<span class="text-xl price">99.99</span></p>
                <p class="text-xs">$<del class="text-sm">119.99</del></p>
              </div>
              <div class="quantity flex items-center space-x-2 py-2 text-white">
                <button class="minus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&minus;</button>
                <p class="quantity-number text-black">1</p>
                <button class="plus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&plus;</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-white mx-4 space-x-2 border-black border">
          <input class="select rounded-full" type="checkbox" name="" id="">
          <img class="w-20 h-20" src="../images/New-and-stylish-Auricularess-Bluetooth-earbuds-custom-waterproof-design-perfect-for-immersive-gaming-experiences/prod1.webp" alt="">
          <div class="grid grod-rows-2 w-full">
            <p class="text-justify text-sm line-clamp-2">New and stylish Auricularess Bluetooth earbuds, custom waterproof design, perfect for immersive gaming experiences.</p>
            <div class="flex justify-between">
              <div class="grid grid-rows-2">
                <p class="text-base font-bold">$<span class="text-xl price">24.99</span></p>
                <p class="text-xs">$<del class="text-sm">29.99</del></p>
              </div>
              <div class="quantity flex items-center space-x-2 py-2 text-white">
                <button class="minus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&minus;</button>
                <p class="quantity-number text-black">1</p>
                <button class="plus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&plus;</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkout bg-white p-4 m-4 md:m-0 md:mr-4 h-fit">
        <p class="font-semibold">Order Summary</p>
        <ul class="py-2 space-y-4">
          <li class="flex justify-between">
            <p>Subtotal (<span class="totalItem">0</span> items)</p>
            <p>$<span class="totalPrice">0</span></p>
          </li>
          <li class="shipping flex justify-between">
            <p>Shipping Fee</p>
            <p>$4</p>
          </li>
          <li class="flex justify-between">
            <p>Total</p>
            <p class="text-blue-600">$<span class="finalPrice">0</span></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="bg-orange-500 text-white py-2 w-full mt-5 hover:bg-orange-600 active:bg-orange-500">Proceed To Checkout (<span class="totalItem">0</span>)</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="side.js"></script>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="scroll-smooth">

<head>
   <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-[#f5f4f4] hide-scrollbar">

   <div class="">
      <h2 class="text-3xl text-center py-8">Your Cart</h2>
      <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3">
         <div class="grid space-y-4 col-span-2">
            <div class="flex justify-between bg-white mx-4 px-4 py-2 border-black border ">
               <div class="flex space-x-4 items-center">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">
                  <p>SELECT ALL</p>
               </div>
               <button>
                  <img class="w-8 h-8" src="../images/main/delete.png" alt="">
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="item flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-white mx-4 space-x-2 border-black border">
               <input class="select rounded-full" type="checkbox" name="" id="">
               <img class="w-20 h-20"
                  src="../images/Cowin-Blue-Wholesale-Aviation-Active-Noise-Cancelling-Headphones-Wired-Gaming-Earphones-Headsets-Bluetooth-Headphones-Wireless/prod1.webp"
                  alt="">
               <div class="grid grod-rows-2 w-full">
                  <p class="text-justify text-sm line-clamp-2">Cowin Blue Wholesale: Aviation Active Noise Cancelling
                     Headphones, Wired Gaming Earphones, Headsets, Bluetooth Headphones, Wireless</p>
                  <div class="flex justify-between">
                     <div class="grid grid-rows-2">
                        <p class="text-base font-bold">$<span class="text-xl price">59.99</span></p>
                        <p class="text-xs">$<del class="text-sm">79.99</del></p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="quantity flex items-center space-x-2 py-2 text-white">
                        <button
                           class="minus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&minus;</button>
                        <p class="quantity-number text-black">1</p>
                        <button
                           class="plus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&plus;</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-white mx-4 space-x-2 border-black border">
               <input class="select rounded-full" type="checkbox" name="" id="">
               <img class="w-20 h-20"
                  src="../images/Modern-soft-and-comfortable-office-E-sports-club-chair-designed-for-ergonomic-gaming-on-computers/prod1.webp"
                  alt="">
               <div class="grid grod-rows-2 w-full">
                  <p class="text-justify text-sm line-clamp-2">Modern, soft, and comfortable office E-sports club chair
                     designed for ergonomic gaming on computers</p>
                  <div class="flex justify-between">
                     <div class="grid grid-rows-2">
                        <p class="text-base font-bold">$<span class="text-xl price">99.99</span></p>
                        <p class="text-xs">$<del class="text-sm">119.99</del></p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="quantity flex items-center space-x-2 py-2 text-white">
                        <button
                           class="minus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&minus;</button>
                        <p class="quantity-number text-black">1</p>
                        <button
                           class="plus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&plus;</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-white mx-4 space-x-2 border-black border">
               <input class="select rounded-full" type="checkbox" name="" id="">
               <img class="w-20 h-20"
                  src="../images/New-and-stylish-Auricularess-Bluetooth-earbuds-custom-waterproof-design-perfect-for-immersive-gaming-experiences/prod1.webp"
                  alt="">
               <div class="grid grod-rows-2 w-full">
                  <p class="text-justify text-sm line-clamp-2">New and stylish Auricularess Bluetooth earbuds, custom
                     waterproof design, perfect for immersive gaming experiences.</p>
                  <div class="flex justify-between">
                     <div class="grid grid-rows-2">
                        <p class="text-base font-bold">$<span class="text-xl price">24.99</span></p>
                        <p class="text-xs">$<del class="text-sm">29.99</del></p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="quantity flex items-center space-x-2 py-2 text-white">
                        <button
                           class="minus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&minus;</button>
                        <p class="quantity-number text-black">1</p>
                        <button
                           class="plus bg-slate-600 w-8 h-8 hover:bg-slate-700 active:bg-slate-800 text-xl flex justify-center">&plus;</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkout bg-white p-4 m-4 md:m-0 md:mr-4 h-fit">
            <p class="font-semibold">Order Summary</p>
            <ul class="py-2 space-y-4">
               <li class="flex justify-between">
                  <p>Subtotal (<span class="totalItem">0</span> items)</p>
                  <p>$<span class="totalPrice">0</span></p>
               </li>
               <li class="shipping flex justify-between">
                  <p>Shipping Fee</p>
                  <p>$4</p>
               </li>
               <li class="flex justify-between">
                  <p>Total</p>
                  <p class="text-blue-600">$<span class="finalPrice">0</span></p>
               </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="bg-orange-500 text-white py-2 w-full mt-5 hover:bg-orange-600 active:bg-orange-500">Proceed
               To Checkout (<span class="totalItem">0</span>)</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script>
      let quantities = document.querySelectorAll(".quantity-number");
      let plusAll = document.querySelectorAll(".plus");
      let minusAll = document.querySelectorAll(".minus");
      let items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
      // document.querySelector("title").innerHTML =
      //    items.length + " items found in Cart";

      let prices = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
      let selectBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".select");
      let selectAll = document.querySelector(".selectAll");
      let totalItem = document.querySelectorAll(".totalItem");
      let totalPrice = document.querySelector(".totalPrice");
      let finalPrice = document.querySelector(".finalPrice");
      quantities.forEach((quantity, index) => {
         let plus = plusAll[index];
         let minus = minusAll[index];
         const checkbox = selectBtn[index]
         let price = Number(prices[index].innerHTML);
         let num = Number(quantity.innerHTML);
         if (num == 1) {
            price = price;
         } else {
            price = Number(prices[index].innerHTML);
            price = price * num;
         };
         plus.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
               totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + price).toFixed(2);
               if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
                  finalPrice.innerHTML = 0;
               } else {
                  finalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + 4).toFixed(2);
               }
            }
            quantity.innerHTML++;
            if (quantity.innerHTML > 1) {
               minus.disabled = false;
            }


         })
         minus.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (quantity.innerHTML <= 1) {
               minus.disabled = true;
            } else {
               minus.disabled = false;
               quantity.innerHTML--;
               if (checkbox.checked) {
                  totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) - price).toFixed(2);
                  if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
                     finalPrice.innerHTML = 0;
                  } else {
                     finalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + 4).toFixed(2);
                  }
               }
            }
         })
      });


      selectAll.addEventListener("input", () => {
         if (selectAll.checked == true) {
            if (btn.checked == false) {
               btn.checked = true;
               let quantity = Number(quantities[index].innerHTML);
               if (quantity == 1) {
                  price = price;
               } else {
                  price = Number(prices[index].innerHTML);
                  price = price * quantity;
               };
               totalItem.forEach((total) => {
                  total.innerHTML++;
               })
               if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
                  totalPrice.innerHTML = (price).toFixed(2);
                  finalPrice.innerHTML = (4 + Number(totalPrice.innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
               } else {
                  totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + price).toFixed(2);
                  finalPrice.innerHTML = (4 + Number(totalPrice.innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
               }
            }
         } else {
            btn.checked = false;
            totalItem.forEach((total) => {
               total.innerHTML--;
            })
            totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) - price).toFixed(2);
            if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
               finalPrice.innerHTML = 0;
            } else {
               finalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + 4).toFixed(2);
            }
         }
      })
      selectBtn.forEach((btn, index) => {
         let price = Number(prices[index].innerHTML);
         btn.addEventListener("input", () => {
            if (btn.checked) {
               let quantity = Number(quantities[index].innerHTML);
               if (quantity == 1) {
                  price = price;
               } else {
                  price = Number(prices[index].innerHTML);
                  price = price * quantity;
               };

               totalItem.forEach((total) => {
                  total.innerHTML++;
               })
               if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
                  totalPrice.innerHTML = (price).toFixed(2);
                  finalPrice.innerHTML = (4 + Number(totalPrice.innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
               } else {
                  totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + price).toFixed(2);
                  finalPrice.innerHTML = (4 + Number(totalPrice.innerHTML)).toFixed(2);
               }
            } else {
               totalItem.forEach((total) => {
                  total.innerHTML--;
               })
               selectAll.checked = false;
               totalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) - price).toFixed(2);
               if (totalPrice.innerHTML == 0) {
                  finalPrice.innerHTML = 0;
               } else {
                  finalPrice.innerHTML = (Number(totalPrice.innerHTML) + 4).toFixed(2);
               }
            }
         })
      })
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for helping me. Also i found a alternate.